# How to search old/legacy TensorFlow documentations efficiently?

Tags: python, tensorflow, documentation, api-doc

I need to check the TensorFlow API documentation for an old TF version (0.12.1). The [website](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/) points me to the GitHub branches. I was able to find my information by checking the code in the sub-packages of the respective branch. However, I am looking for a way to efficiently search old api information, i.e. using the search bar provided on the website and the hierarchical tree search (left hand-side on website) etc.

Is there faster way and if so, what's the best way except searching through .md and code files in this case?

Comment: I didn't found comfortable sollution. But you can use duckduckgo, when you ask `tensorflow r1.15 <searching term>` then with high probability you will get proper page of tensorflow documentation